# How to check for duplicates in an HTMLcollection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First time, please be gentle, I'm just starting to learn Javascript.

I am trying to build a tally counter where you can tally multiple things at the same time. I have a settings panel where you can add or change the key bindings by typing your preferred key binding into a text input. I have buttons that add or delete these input pairs using Javascript so the number of these input pairs is always changing.

```
<input class="key-binding"></input>
<input class="tallied-item"></input>

<input class="key-binding"></input>
<input class="tallied-item"></input>

<input class="key-binding"></input>
<input class="tallied-item"></input>
```

I have the key bindings saved to an HTMLcollection and I have an event-listener set up on the document that executes a function when the event 'input' is triggered on "key-binding" class. I can't get the function to properly check for duplicate entries since I don't want the same key binding to be set up for more than one item. Using a standard for loop doesn't work since the HTMLcollection changes when I add or delete input pairs. Here's what I have so far:

```
let keyBindings = document.getElementsByClassName('key-binding');
function dupKeyCheck(){
tempArray = []
Array.from(keyBindings).forEach(function(element) {
    let value  = element.value;
    if (tempArray.indexOf(element) == -1){
        tempArray.push(value)
    } else {
        //execute some code when duplicate entry is found
    }
})
}
```

If this can be done much simpler using jQuery, I'd be interested in seeing that as well.

Comment: _"Using a standard for loop doesn't work since the HTMLcollection changes"_ - Why should this be a problem? `for (let i = 0; i < keyBindings.length; i++) { ... }` doesn't care about the fact that the content of `keyBindings` might change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.prototype.filter on your event handler, where you can compare event.target.value against other values

```
dupes = Array.from(keyBindings).filter((i) => i !== event.target && i.value == event.target.value).length;
```